# Using attribute routing and convention based routing with Web API and MVC simultaneously

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have an Asp.net MVC web application that uses convention based routing. I recently added some Web Api 2 controllers, for which I used attribute routing. Despite the documentation claiming that you can use both, I can either get the (attribute routed) API methods to work, or the (convention routed) web application methods.

This is RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes():

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        //routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Tables", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "Foo.Cms.Controllers" }
        );
    }
```

This is WebApiConfig.Register():

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Uncomment the following line of code to enable query support for actions with an IQueryable or IQueryable<T> return type.
        // To avoid processing unexpected or malicious queries, use the validation settings on QueryableAttribute to validate incoming queries.
        // For more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=279712.
        //config.EnableQuerySupport();


        // The models currently only serialize succesfully to xml, so we'll remove the json formatter.
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
    }
```

And this is Application_Start():

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
    }
```

This way, only the routing to the web api controllers works. If I switch GlobalConfiguration.Register() and RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(), like so:

```
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

...only the convention-based routing works.

I'm at a loss. What's going on here?

Edit:

What I'm trying to achieve:

The application currently uses the basic {controller}/{action}/parameters convention. So I have a controller called ElementsController that has, for instance, an Index() method that is routed to /Elements or a ListPublic() method that is routed to /Elements/ListPublic. I achieved this with the convention based routing mentioned above.

I also have a bunch of Web Api controllers (for instance, TablesController) that I want to route to using a /api/v0/tables route. I tried to achieve this like so:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v0/tables")]
public class TablesController : ApiController
{
    [Route()]
    public string Get()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's not the same route pattern: api calls are all prefixed with api/v0/. For some reason though, it still appears to treat them as the default {controller}/{action} routes.

Answer (score 1):

What's occurring is that the "first registered" route is taking effect. If I have a MVC route defined as 
`{controller}/{action}/{id}`

and a Web API route defined as

`{controller}/{action}/{id}`

The first registered route will take effect.

Why is this the case? Imagine you send a request to the server

`foo/bar/1`

Which route does this match?

Both!

It will choose the first result that matches the route **regardless of the type of routing used**. If you want some examples as to how to make these routings work, check out this [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: So how would I go about having both take effect?

Comment: You are going to need to change your routing. Give an example as to what you are trying to do

Comment: You should edit your original question, because this answer isn't an answer. Please, update your question with this info, or, at least move this to a comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If an URL matches two different route templates, it doesn't matter if they refer to MVC or Web API, the only rule is that the first registered route will be used to select the action to execute.

In your particular case, if you make a GET request to this URL: `/api/v0/tables`, the action selector starts checking the registered routes.

The first route that you're registering is an MVC route like this: `/{controller}/{action}/{id}`. So, the template matches with this values:

```
controller = "api"
action = "v0"
id = "tables"
```

If you register the attribute routes before the MVC route, the first matching route template will be your route attribute template, so the Web API controller action will be correctly selected.

In other words, if you need to route Web API and MVC in the same application you have to use routes which match different URLs for each action, and be careful with the order in which they are registered: register first the more specific templates, and then the more generic ones, so that the generic templates doesn't swallow the URIs which should be matched with the specific templates.

This is not the only option. You can also use route constraints, for example, if all your API has a particular naming convention which can be checked with a constraint (for example a Regex constraint), you can still use convention routing for Web API.

*NOTE: apart from the route matching, it's also necessary that the HTTP method (like POST, GET, etc.) is supported by the action. So you can have two similar actions in the same route that accept different methods, and the Action selector would know which one to choose, but this doesn't solve your problem*

Comment: I've edited the question to include this information, but I don't see how they can match the same route templates, since all the attribute-routed controllers have api/v0/ prefixed to them.

Comment: Let's see... you query `/api/v0/tables`. The first route that you're registering is an MVC route like this: `/{controller}/{action}/{id}`. So... *controller = api, action = v0, id = tables* Register the attribute routes before the MVC route, and it shoukd work. If not, leave a new message.

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes sense. Unfortunately, registering the attribute route before the mvc route doesn't work, because that way -only- the attribute routes work, and not the mvc routes.

Comment: Mmmm, that's strange. However you can still solve it by adding a constraint to the `controller` in the MVC route that rejects the `api`. It looks trivial, by making it work. For example this regex matches anything bu t `api`: `^(?!api$).*`

Comment: I can assure that you can register first the Web API, and then the MVC, ot the other way round, and they work as I have explained. As it lloks like you still have some issue, please, add the route configurations, and the failing URL. Please, start your project with only the MVC routing registered, and try your MVC part. Then do the same with the Web API. If both of them work on their own, they should also work together, registering them in any order.

Comment: I've mentioned the route configurations in my original question. And I've tried them on their own, which works, but when used together, only the routing I registered first will work.

Comment: The route constraints did the trick. It still feels like a kludge, but at least it does what it's supposed to do now.

Comment: I insist that you must have some particular problem in your configuration. I tested it with the deafult MVC route, which in fact "swallowed" the `api/v0/tables`, but when I registered it in the other order (first WebAPI, then MVC), both the MVC and the Web API routes worked fine. I used exactly the same route attribute in your question to test it.